# Sending a work email. Does this sound professional. A little lost, help please!

Tags: grammaticality

All,

I found a problem with the setup of our Merchant Accounts that has affected our sales. We have had a lot of recent declines from our customers within Limelight and the reason is our Merchant Accounts are requiring a CVV code after our initial order.

Can someone please fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds fine as it is to me. It would be more effective if you could address it an individual who can act on it. Perhaps you can ask who that would be.

Comment: If you want to sound professional I would practice, and start with the title of your question.

Comment: your email should make it clear that you have thought carefully about the problem, and that you are suggesting solutions rather than simply drawing attention to an issue. give numbers of customers affected by the issue, examples of sales lost due to this problem, and a suggested fix. if you can do all of that, no one will care about your English.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem with the setup of our Merchant Accounts that has negatively impacted our new sales. Due to a post-order CVV code requirement, we are experiencing an inordinate amount of declines from our Limelight customers.

I wrote "new sales" as it is my impression these are initial, and not repeat orders.  To professionally polish your letter, present a solution, or request help on resolving this sales issue

Comment: If at all possible, explain exactly how to provoke the problem, and enclose the exact text of any error messages or erroneous output. (But this is a working-with-others point, not a language use point.)